# How to save mongodb backup file outside of container using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am trying to take backup of mongodb using cron job in Node.js. As my node.js is running with docker so its storing file inside docker container. I am explaining my code below.

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const shell = require('shelljs');
// Cron job to take mongodb backup.

cron.schedule('59 20 * * *', function() {
  console.log('---------------------');
  console.log('Running Cron Job');
  if (shell.exec(`mongodump --host 127.0.0.1 -d test-db --port 27017 --out "mongobackup_$(date +'%d_%m_%Y')"`).code !== 0) {
    shell.exit(1);
  }
  else {
    shell.echo('Database backup complete');
  }
});
```

Here I am taking mongodb backup using `shelljs` module in everyday 9PM. But my node server is running through docker so its storing the backup file inside that docker environment.

Here I need to store same file outside of the container means inside servers root directory. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Why not to use cron directly and exclude nodejs from the equation at all? Regarding the backup - either map a directory to the host system, use persistent volumes, or push the backup to the external service, e.g. a cloud storage.

Comment: You can use docker volumes for this. Mount docker volume to container and write backup file to volume.

Comment: @AlexBlex, Can you post your answer please ?